# Java - using a downloaded package without IDE

Tags: java, command-line

I am quite new to Java. I am still developing with a simple text editor to better understand how the inclusion of packages works for Java.

I have my file Test.java, whose first two lines are:

```
import java.util.List;  
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

I have tried to download the package google-gson and unzip it in the same directory where Test.java is.

```
|-- google-gson-1.5
|   |-- gson-1.5.jar
|   |-- gson-1.5-javadoc.jar
|   |-- gson-1.5-sources.jar
|   |-- LICENSE
|   `-- README
`-- Test.java
```

But when I try to launch:

```
javac Test.java
```

I get this error message:

```
Test.java:2: package com.google.gson does not exist
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

What should I do to make things work (using the command line and a simple editor)?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Eventually I did this: javac -cp google-gson-1.5/gson-1.5.jar Test.java &&
java -cp google-gson-1.5/gson-1.5.jar:./ Test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Test.java is not assigned to a package:

Compile:

```
javac -cp .;google-gson-1.5\gson-1.5.jar Test.java
```

Run:

```
java -cp .;google-json-1.5\gson-1.5.jar Test
```

If you want to add more JARs:

```
javac -cp .;google-gson-1.5\gson-1.5.jar;anotherlib\anotherlib.jar Test.java
```

(Note: Windows syntax shown.  On *Nix systems, use `:` instead of `;` and `/` instead of `\`)

As long as you intend on using the `javac` and `java` command line interfaces directly, I recommend creating a `build.bat` and a `run.bat` (or `build.sh` and `run.sh` on *Nix) to store the `javac` and `java` incantations that you compose.  These scripts make it easier to:

1. remember the correct build/run command structure several days later
2. send a ready-to-build/ready-to-run copy of the project to someone else
3. let you edit the commands in a text editor, rather than on the command line

[**Ant**](http://ant.apache.org/): Once you are comfortable with using `java` and `javac` on the command line and through shell scripts, it might be time to investigate migrating to Ant's powerful framework, which is great for maintaining all your build, test, and run configurations.

Comment: "I highly recommend creating a "build.bat" and a "run.bat"" ?!?!!! Use ant! It's much easier.

Comment: Jason - I agree. I use and love ant. I recommended shell scripts in this case because our humble asker is clearly very new to Java and wants to experience the "bare bones" essentials of Java. While ant is less opaque than an IDE, it is still a layer of abstraction. The shell script I recommended is essentially just a way to save a command-line command for later use.

Comment: Or maybe he could just use and IDE that takes care of that for him? IMO the whole point of this exercise is to experience the pain of using java without any aids. Ant will just cushion the blow.

Comment: It compiles but when I tried to run java -cp google-gson-1.5/gson-1.5.jar  Test, I got: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test

Comment: This did the magic: java -cp google-gson-1.5/gson-1.5.jar:./ Test            Is that normal?

Comment: Dan: yes, it is normal, and it's something I forgot. The current directory (`.`) is not automatically added to the classpath. By adding it to the classpath, you enabled Java to find 'Test.class' which is in `.`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to compiler your java program, you'll either need the sources in the folder that fits the packaged (for example com.google.gson package must be in com\google\gson folder)or you'll need to place your gson-1.5.jar in the Classpath [[Explanation here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html)].

I think setting the classpath via javac should be the recommended solution in this case.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. How can I place gson-1.5.jar in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: There is a link now. I think `javac -classpath root\google-gson-1.5
\gson-1.5.jar WhatYouWantToCompile` should work but I'm not hundred percent sure it will. root stands for the folder where google-gson-1.5 is located (if that is somehow unclear)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It compiles but when I try to run it: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
 at Test.main(Test.java:26)

Comment: There are several way to add a file to a classpath. You can also add its path to a CLASSPATH variable (the method for that differs from platform). PS. Seeing the answer, below did you use the classpath attribute for both compiling and running?